# Source of truth for raising events in an Event-driven architecture?

Tags: architecture, entity-component-system

I am developing a turn-based strategy game and am using Events to implement a "Buff" / "Debuff" system. The code is very OOP-y right now, not very ECS.

I am adding an event system similar to the one described here: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/event-queue.html.

The motivation is if a unit is damaged, there could be some condition called "OnDamage" that maybe triggers an AoE ability around them.

The problem is I am not sure what the source of truth for where the event should be raised should be.

I have a class:

```csharp
class Unit 
{
    int hp;

    ...

    void UpdateHp(...)
    {
         // clamp HP above 0, calculate shields, etc.
    }
}

class State
{
    ...

    map<string, coordinate> unitLocations;

    func updateUnitLocation(unitId, newLoc)
    {
        unitLocations[iconId] = newLoc;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

We also have this concept of `Modifiers` which are functions that change State. An example is a `DamageModifier` which takes in the `State` and calculates some `Damage`, then calls `UpdateHp(...)` on that unit.

Example modifier:

```csharp
void Execute(State state, EventManager em, Unit initiatorUnit, List<Unit> targetUnits)
{
    long totalDamage = 0;
    foreach (var unit in targets)
    {
        int oldHealth = target.GetHp();
        int damage = CalculateDamage(initiator, defender); // based on some stats
        int newHealth = oldHp - damage;
        target.UpdateHp(newHealth);
    }
}
```

My question is where are events generally raised? If a Unit moves I thought I would raise the event from `UpdateLocation`, but we could also do it in the `MoveModifier`. With the former there is a single source of the event. All modifiers that do movement must go through that function. We have multiple "modifiers" now that need to raise the `MoveEvent`, such as a `DisplacementModifier`, `MoveModifier`.

For `Damage`, we could raise the `DamageEvent` from the `Unit` class. The problem is the Unit class now takes a dependency on the `EventManager`. I think that might be OK to make sure there's a single source of truth for all of those. We also have 2-3 DamageModifiers, one that does flat damage, one that calculates it based on stats.

Former:

```csharp
class Unit 
{
    int hp;

    ...

    void UpdateHp(..., EventManager em)
    {
         // clamp HP above 0, calculate shields, etc.
         em.Raise(new DamageEvent(...));
    }
}

class State
{
    ...

    map<string, coordinate> unitLocations;

    func updateUnitLocation(unitId, newLoc, EventManager em)
    {
        unitLocations[iconId] = newLoc;
        em.Raise(new MoveEvent(...));
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Latter:

```csharp
func void Execute(State state, EventManager em, Unit initiatorUnit, List<Unit> targetUnits)
{
    long totalDamage = 0;
    foreach (var unit in targets)
    {
        int oldHealth = target.GetHp();
        int damage = CalculateDamage(initiator, defender); // based on some stats
        int newHealth = oldHp - damage;
        target.UpdateHp(newHealth);

        em.Raise(new DamageEvent(...)); // processed later
    }
}
```

On the flip side, these "modifiers" seem like the "systems" in ECS. In the ECS world as I understand it, the events are generally raised in the systems and its ok if the same event is raised in multiple systems. For instance, fall damage in a physics system, or damage from a combat/ability system, or damage from a fatigue system.

The main difference I see is the modifier way makes it the caller's responsibility to raise the event, and that seems dangerous but potentially more flexible.

Also interested in any resources on ECS. I can't find anything that goes deep with example systems, just surface level things.